# How do I install Ubuntu 12.04 on an Asus g74sx- bbk7?

Tags: installation, asus

I have a problem when I try to install Ubuntu on my laptop. When I choose the option "install", the screen is black and I can't continue the install.

I read some to edit with command line, how write the command `pci=nomsi` and `acpi=off` but didn't a result.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ubuntu's Windows installer (Wubi) if you are running Windows.

Comment: I have tried intall from ubuntu windows installer and from the grub  but the result is the same. When begin the intallation the screen turn black and no continue...